# how can i replace Date of birth missing values with average Date of birth based on Titel Column in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, missing-data, powerbi-desktop

For example, The average of Date of birh ( for Mr ) is 07/01/1971 !
what I want is to replace every missing values where Titel=Mr with 07/01/1971 !
I want this to be automatically done by using Power Query M.

Thank you very much for your interest and your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Change type of Birth date do whole number
2. Group by Title by Average of Birth Date
3. Merge queries with the current table, set columns to Title in both instances
4. Go to advanced editor and in the last step modify the nested join function: in the first argument replace the #"Group rows" step with the name of the last step before changed Birth Date type
5. Expand the new column with AVG Birth Date
6. Change the type of AVG Birth Date to date
7. Add new custom column: if [Birth Date] = null then [AVG Birth Date] else [Birth Date]
8. Remove the two original columns and change the name of the original column to Birth Date

Comment: how would you group by Average of Birth Date?

Comment: Home Ribbon -> Group by -> Title, New Column Name: AVG Birth Date, Operation: Average,  Column: Birth Date

Comment: But there is no Average Birth Date column. You have to average the birth dates

Comment: Yes, AVG Birth Date is the name of the new grouped column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to replace all the nulls with a pre-determined date if title =Mr?

Add column ... custom column ..

```
= if [Titel]="Mr" and [Geburtsdatum]=null then #date(1971,1,7) else [Geburtsdatum]
```

then remove the original and rename the new column as Geburtsdatum

If we have to calculate average birth date, why is the average date of birth for (Mr) 07/01/1971 for the sample? The datevalues of your sample are 21/10/1945=16731, 30/09/1971=26206, etc, and they average out to be 19962 which is 26/08/1954

Assuming that the average birthday is just the average of the datevalues, the below would work

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
AverageBirthdateMr=Date.From(List.Average(Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Titel] = "Mr" and [Geburtsdatum] <> null))[Geburtsdatum])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [Titel]="Mr" and [Geburtsdatum]=null then AverageBirthdateMr else [Geburtsdatum]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Geburtsdatum"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", "Geburtsdatum"}}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Geburtsdatum", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue?